# Task scheduling gets stuck

Tags: java, optaplanner

I am currently trying to get my grip on OptaPlanner as it seems to be the perfect solution for [a problem I have](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/237431/algorithm-to-calculate-scheduling-of-task-list-check-feasability).

Basically the [Project job scheduling](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/use-cases-and-examples/project-job-scheduling/project-job-scheduling.html#projectJobScheduling) example is what I am going for, but as I only know my Java basics this is way to complex to start with. So I am trying to start with a very limited example and work my way up from there:

I have tasks with a duration and one defined predecessor.
The planning entity is the time each task starts.

I have a hard score that punishes tasks starting before starttime+duration of its predecessor. I also have a soft score that tries to reduce gaps, keeping the overall process as short as possible.

```
public HardSoftScore calculateScore(Schedule schedule) {
    int hardScore = 0;
    int softScore = 0;

    for (Task task : schedule.getTaskList()) {
        int endTime = task.getAllocation().getStartTime() + task.getDuration();
        softScore = -endTime;

        for (Task task2 : schedule.getTaskList()) {
            if(task.getId()!=task2.getId()){
                if( task2.getPredecessorId()==task.getId()) {
                    if (endTime > task2.getAllocation().getStartTime()) {
                        hardScore += task2.getAllocation().getStartTime() - endTime;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return HardSoftScore.valueOf(hardScore, softScore);

}
```

This is the solver config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<solver>
    <!--<environmentMode>FAST_ASSERT</environmentMode>-->

    <!-- Domain model configuration -->
    <solutionClass>com.foo.scheduler.domain.Schedule</solutionClass>
    <planningEntityClass>com.foo.scheduler.domain.Task</planningEntityClass>

    <!-- Score configuration -->
    <scoreDirectorFactory>
        <scoreDefinitionType>HARD_SOFT</scoreDefinitionType>
        <simpleScoreCalculatorClass>com.foo.scheduler.solver.score.SchedulingSimpleScoreCalculator</simpleScoreCalculatorClass>
    </scoreDirectorFactory>

    <!-- Optimization algorithms configuration -->
    <termination>
        <maximumSecondsSpend>100</maximumSecondsSpend>
    </termination>
    <constructionHeuristic>
        <constructionHeuristicType>FIRST_FIT</constructionHeuristicType>
    </constructionHeuristic>
    <localSearch>
        <acceptor>
            <entityTabuSize>7</entityTabuSize>
        </acceptor>
        <forager>
            <acceptedCountLimit>1000</acceptedCountLimit>
        </forager>
    </localSearch>
</solver>
```

**The problem is that this works great as long as I only have the hard score. But of course it has gaps. As soon as I add the soft score everything gets stuck after about 10 steps. Why?**

```
[...]
2014-05-03 20:01:31,966 [main] DEBUG     Step index (10), time spend (495), score (-35hard/-66soft),     best score (-34hard/-68soft), accepted/selected move count (1000/19884) for picked step (com.foo.scheduler.domain.Task@35480096 => com.foo.scheduler.domain.Allocation@f9a4520).
2014-05-03 20:03:11,471 [main] DEBUG     Step index (11), time spend (100000), score (-35hard/-65soft),     best score (-34hard/-68soft), accepted/selected move count (0/105934687) for picked step (com.foo.scheduler.domain.Task@7050c91f => com.foo.scheduler.domain.Allocation@47c44bd4).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A selected move count of `105934687` at step 11 clearly indicates that no move is being accepted. I don't see how a soft score could trigger that though. There is only 1 explanation:

- The `EntityTabuAcceptor` doesn't accept any move, because they are all tabu, which means every move's planning entities are in the tabu list. This is possible if you have very small dataset (`14` or less planning entities). **Turn on TRACE logging and the log will confirm this.**

Each of these workaround should fix that:

- Use *Late Acceptance*

  ```
  <acceptor>
    <lateAcceptanceSize>400</lateAcceptanceSize>
  </acceptor>
  <forager>
    <acceptedCountLimit>1</acceptedCountLimit>
  </forager>
  ```
- Use `<entityTabuRatio>` instead of `<entityTabuSize>`
- Mess with the `<entityTabuSize>` based on the dataset size with `SolverFactory.getSolverConfig()`. Not recommended!

Why less than 14 planning entities?

Because by default you get a `<changeMoveSelector>` and a `<swapMoveSelector>`. The `<swapMoveSelector>` swaps 2 entities, making both tabu if it wins a step. The tabu list size is the number of steps, so if 7 swap moves win the steps in a row, there can be 14 entities in the tabu list.

Comment: [I created this JIRA to track this issue.](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-237)